# How to insert high quality Bitmap image in android into Gallery

Tags: android, bitmap, image-gallery

I know the insert method

```
  MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(..............)
```

Insert a thumbnail instaed of the original Bitmap image,I need a way to save Bitmap with no compress to keep its pixels as they are (steganography), I need the image to be stored on gallery in internal storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gallery can contains folders for application on android, to get high resolution file there is need to store them outside the gallery and tell gallery about your file and your application folder and show your files as thumbnails,so I implement this method which perform what I need and I hope help others

```
  private void SaveImage(Bitmap segg) {

    OutputStream fOut = null;
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fileName = "Image-"+ n +".png";
    final String appDirectoryName = "TBStego";
    final File imageRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), appDirectoryName);

    imageRoot.mkdirs();
    final File file = new File(imageRoot, fileName);
    try {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    segg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
    try {
        Toast.makeText(ExtractActivity.this,
                file.getAbsolutePath(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,"stego");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "stego description");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID, file.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.US).hashCode());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, file.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.US));
    values.put("_data", file.getAbsolutePath());
    Toast.makeText(ExtractActivity.this,
            file.getAbsolutePath(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    Toast.makeText(ExtractActivity.this, "The Image thumbnail created in Gallery ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```