# Saving Bitmap without Losing Quality (Gradient background)

Tags: android-studio, bitmap

I have created a bitmap that forms a linear gradient background. I am trying to save it into the device's storage but the saved image has very low quality.

Code to save the bitmap image:

```
public void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        String filename = "dy/dx_wallpaper-" + System.currentTimeMillis();
        String url = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, filename, "Gradient Wallpaper");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved as " + url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Image should be like this

[image: Image should be like this]

But it's like this

[image: But it's like this]

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance folks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the insertImage method only stores a thumbnail of the original bitmap. Here is a possible solution which may help:

[How to insert high quality Bitmap image in android into Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35814674/how-to-insert-high-quality-bitmap-image-in-android-into-gallery)

Comment: Dayumnn... You're a livesaver... Thank you soo much... <3 <3 :)